# Real analysis question on tangent and secant sets of function on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a differentiable function in an interval $I$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Define 
\begin{align}
X = \{f'(x) | x \in I\} \quad Y=\left\{\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y};\; x,y \in I, x \neq y\right\} 
\end{align}
Prove that $\overline{X} = \overline{Y}$.

Comment: $\overline{Y} \subset \overline{X}$ is clear to me, since $ Y \subset X $, but the converse isn't...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $m \in X$.  Then $m = f'(c)$ for some $c \in I$.  If we take a sequence $x_n \to c$, then the definition of a derivative tells us that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n) - f(c)}{x_n - c} = f'(c)
$$

Comment: If I understood correctly, then as $\frac{f(x_n) - f(c)}{x_n - c}$ is a sequence of Y, it's limit is in $\overline{Y}$, thus $X \subset \overline{Y}$, thus $\overline{X} \subset \overline{Y}$. Is that it?

Comment: That's right. Any closed set containing $X$ contains $\bar X$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

By mean value theorem you have

$$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}  = f' (c)  $$

Where $c \in (x,y)$ This shows $Y \subseteq X$ so $\bar{Y} \subseteq \bar{X}$

for other way take $f'(c) \in X$ then there exist the sequence, say  $\{ \frac{f(x_n) - f(c)}{x_n - c} \}  \in Y$ such that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n) - f(c)}{x_n - c} = f'(c)$$

Even you can prove $X = \bar{Y}$ .i.e, $X$ is closed set if $ I $ is compact interval.  I think!